# Adding JS to Site

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I am trying to add some .JS to my site to make my navigation 'MENU' slide down (rather than just appear). This is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NL6PV/2133/

Here is my actual Magento html code:

```
<div class="skip-links">

<a class="skip-link skip-nav" href="#header-nav">

<span class="icon"></span>
<span class="label">

    MENU

</span>
```

Then I added the following into my '/app.js'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.skip-links').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-skip-links" class="button">Open/Close</a>');
$('a#toggle-skip-links').click(function() {
    $('.skip-links').slideToggle(200);
    return false;
});
});
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your jQuery would be conflicting with prototype (if your magento site is running with prototype)

add noconflict after jQuery core is loaded but before the jquery run code

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and use jQuery instead of $ in your jquery code...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.skip-links').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-skip-links" class="button">Open/Close</a>');
jQuery('a#toggle-skip-links').click(function() {
jQuery('.skip-links').slideToggle(200);
return false;
});
});
```

hopefully that should do the trick..